# dxa and reference-implementation tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We have two tags for the same thing: [dxa](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dxa) and [reference-implementation](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-implementation).

The new name for the Tridion Reference implementaton is DXA: Digital Experience Accellerator, so I think we should keep only [dxa](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dxa). In the tag wiki we can explain that it is the referene implementation also known as TSI, STRI, TRI or RI.

In case we keep [dxa](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dxa): All questions with [dxa](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dxa) are also tagged with [reference-implementation](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-implementation). So we can 1) remove the [dxa](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dxa) tag and then rename [reference-implementation](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-implementation) to [dxa](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dxa).

Answer (score 2):

We can't rename or remove tags, but I can merge [dxa](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dxa) and [reference-implementation](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-implementation), so that the latter becomes a synonym of the first, and when anybody tries to use [reference-implementation](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-implementation), they get [dxa](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dxa) automatically (and all existing posts will also get that tag).